# What is the reason for making usage of sealed classes in when expression behave differently if when is used as an expression and not as a statement?

Tags: kotlin

If you use sealed classes with `when`, [Kotlin treats `when` differently if you use it as expression than if you use it as a statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html).

For example, this piece of code when I use `when` as a statement is valid :

```
sealed class SomeType
object Foo: SomeType()
object Bar: SomeType()

fun test(input: SomeType) {
    when(input) {
        is Foo -> {}
    }
}
```

But this one when I use it as an expression is not because because `when` expects either `else` branch or that the code checks for all subtypes of `SomeType` where `Bar` is missing in the example code :

```
sealed class SomeType
object Foo: SomeType()
object Bar: SomeType()

fun test(input: SomeType) {
    var result = when(input) {
        is Foo -> {}
    }
}
```

What is the reason behind this design decision?

And my question is, what if I don't care about the result (not want to use `when` as an expression), just want to execute some code that returns `Unit` for each `when` branch, but I want to have the behavior where Kotlin will throw an error at compile-time if I have not used all the subtypes of sealed class in `when` statement? My only option is to use a dummy variable, so I force `when` statement to be an expression even though I don't care about the result? Any other way to achieve such behavior (compile-time check if all the cases are checked), maybe without `when`?

Comment: It sounds to me, as if that specific function could rather be part of `SomeType` and/or delivered by its subtypes, e.g. if you add an abstract function to `SomeType` you would be forced to implement it for all its subtypes and there would be no way to overcome that... that would be better than hoping that all `when` and `if`s have all the possible conditions in them... and no: I do not know of any inspection or tool to check if `when`/`if` are used exhaustively :-)

Comment: Actually, even your first sample does not compile for me using Kotlin 1.7:  _'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'else' branch_

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is a strongly typed language, which forces you to declare explicetely a type when you declare a value.

[Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24434/strongly-typed):

> Strongly typed is a concept used to refer to a programming language
>   that enforces strict restrictions on intermixing of values with
>   differing data types. When such restrictions are violated and error
>   (exception) occurs.

In your first case, the `when` is a **statement**, which practically means that if any condition applies, it is executed, if not - it is ignored. Nothing happens with that statement afterwards.

In the second case, `when` is an **expression** which creates a value - it can only detect the type by itself when all conditions are covered, including `else`.

[Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) says:

> If *when* is used as an expression, the *else* branch is mandatory, unless
>   the compiler can prove that all possible cases are covered with branch
>   conditions

Same applies to If/else:

> Just like with *if*, each branch can be a block, and its value is the
>   value of the last expression in the block.

```
val result1 = if(true) 1 //will not compile
val result2 = if(true) 1 else 2 // will compile
```